# Run two actions in component

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I would like to dispatch below actions, after clicked button, but one by one (like a mergeMap) or run second action after first's success.

Important thing - in component, not effect class etc.

````
case BtnType.BTN_TEST: {
                this.store$.dispatch(action1({
                 // some data
                }));

                this.store$.dispatch(
                    action12({
                         // some data
                    }));
                break;
            }
    ```
````

Comment: To fire action one by one and waiting for the first one to finish, it has to be handled in the effects, effect has the knowledge when the service or side effect is successful.

Answer (score 0):

Simply subscribe to  your `Ngrx` store using a selector which would be affected by your first action, once a new value arrived, dispatch the next.

```js
 case BtnType.BTN_TEST: {
      this.store$.dispatch(action1({
        // some data
      }));

      this.store.pipe(select(getHeroes))
        .subscribe(x => {

            this.store$.dispatch(action12({
              // some data
            }));

        })

      break;
    }
```

Optionally you can inject `Actions` to your constructor and wait for the first action to get dispatched using `ofType` operator function just as you would in an `Effect`.

```js
 constructor(
   private actions$: Actions,
   private store: Store<AppState>,
 ) { }

...
case BtnType.BTN_TEST: {

    this.store$.dispatch(action1({});

    this.actions$
      .pipe(
        ofType(ActionTypes.Action1),
        first()
      )
      .subscribe(x => {

        this.store$.dispatch(action12({
          // some data
        }));

      })

    break;
  }
```

Note: both options are not considered best practice, as event dispating should never be done asynchronously.